# ant build version with leading zeros

Tags: ant, build

I want my version numbers of the installer files to be like `installer-02`.

I have the following entry in `<entry key="build.number" type="int" value="2" />`

How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `pattern` for int type when you add `entry` to property file http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html.

```
<propertyfile
  file="my.properties"
  comment="My properties">
   <entry key="build.number" type="int" value="2" pattern="00"/>
</propertyfile>

<property file="my.properties"/>

<echo message="build.number : ${build.number}"/>
```

Please note with above eg, it will prefix build # with 0 for values from 0-9.